# How does the php print (or echo) commands interpret math symbols?

Tags: php

I am learning php and the code is strictly for my education so I am not looking for "better" ways of doing this.

As I am going over the language I am trying out everything and also creating a document of what I am trying.  I am finding some strange behavior of the echo and print command and would like to know:

1) Do I really need 3 lines to print "2 + 3 = 5"

2) What is really happening?  Why do I get a 6 in example #2?

Example 1 - Doesn't work, seems to evaluate no matter what I do.  Single quotes, double quotes even escaping the plus ("2 /+ 3") does not work.

```
echo('2 + 3 = '.$var1 + $var2.'<br>');// 5
echo("2 + 3 = ".$var1 + $var2.'<br>');// 5
echo('2 /+ 3 /= '.$var1 + $var2.'<br>');// 5
```

Example 2 - Now its getting strange because I get 6.  If I change the 3 to a 4 I get 7 so its almost like " 3 = " = 1 and " 4 = " = 2 then implicitly add to the following but I doubt that.

```
echo("2 + ");
echo(" 3 = ".$var1 + $var2.'<br>');// 2 + 6?
echo("2 + ");
echo(" 4 = ".$var1 + $var2.'<br>');// 2 + 7??
```

Example 3 - Do I really need 3 lines to accomplish my task?  Strating to remind me of Fortran.

```
echo("2 + ");
echo(" 3 = ");
echo($var1 + $var2.'<br>');// 2 + 3 = 5
```

To help clear things up var1 = 2 and var2 = 3.  The values are irrelevant.  I am just trying to enclose a literal and an evaluated exprerssion.

I want to have code echo '2 + 3 = '.$var1 + $var2.'
' that results in '2 + 3 = 5' but all I get is 5 or 2 + 3 = 2 + 3.

Why only one 5 here?

```
echo('2 + 3 = '.$var1 + $var2.'<br>');// 5
```

Why is it not evaluation the second expression?

```
echo('2 + 3 = '."$var1 + $var2".'<br>');// 2 + 3 = 2 + 3
```

Comment: It's all about HOW you're echoing them. Single quotes will take strings as literals, meaning '2 + 3 = 5' will echo exactly that. While double quotes allow variables(and math) to be used. So "2 + 3 = 5" will result in: "5 = 5".

Comment: Could you edit your question so we can see the values of `$var1` and `$var2`?

Comment: @Andrei, yes you are correct.  The problem becomes evident when literals are mixed with expressions.  You did not provide an example of that.  Is that because this is not possible with php?  Is my mistake from trying to do too much on one line?  Perhaps php is not as capable as I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrei pointed out, it was because of the order of operations.  I found [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), specifically:

> A word of caution - the dot operator has the same precedence as + and -, which can yield unexpected results.
>
> Example:

```
<php
$var = 3;

echo "Result: " . $var + 3;
?>
```

> The above will print out "3" instead of "Result: 6", since first the string "Result3" is created and this is then added to 3 yielding 3, non-empty non-numeric strings being converted to 0.
>
> To print "Result: 6", use parantheses to alter precedence:

```
<php
$var = 3;

echo "Result: " . ($var + 3);
?>
```

So my solution is:

```
echo '2 + 3 = '.($var1 + $var2).'<br>'; //result: 2 + 3 = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

First lets take a look at single and double quotes. Lets say we have the following variable:

```
$var1 = 1;
```

If we echo this variable with single or double quotes:

```
echo "$var1"; //result: 1
echo '$var1'; //result: $var1
```

So double quotes will echo the value while single quotes will simply echo the literal variable name as if it's just a string.

Now lets take a look at Example 1. In this case it doesn't matter what type of quotes or escape chars (which is a backslash: \ and not a forward slash: /) you use, because you're not echoing the variables inside the quotes:

```
echo "string" . $var1 + $var2 . "more strings";
```

As you can see, `$var1` and `$var2` are outside of the quotes. They're simply added to it by the dot `.` character. So if we'd modify example one, the results would be different:

```
echo '2 + 3 = $var1 + $var2<br>'; //result: 2 + 3 = $var1 + $var2
echo "2 + 3 = $var1 + $var2<br>";//result: 2 + 3 = 5
echo '2 /+ 3 /= $var1 + $var2<br>';//result: 2 /+ 3 /= $var1 + $var2
```

In the last echo it's completely pointless to try to escape the plus and/or equal sign. Escape characters in PHP is a technique to prevent your strings from ending to early, or for making sure you have the correct string information returned. For example:

```
echo 'John's Car'; //This will return an error
echo 'John\'s Car'; //This will work perfectly fine
```

In the first case, PHP notices the second single quote somewhere inside our string. It assumes we're ending our string right there, while we ment to put a literal quote inside our string. The escape char tells PHP we want to put a single quote inside our string and not end it right there.

Unfortunetely I can't help you with Example 2 because your problem can't be duplicated without having the values of `$var1` and `$var2`.

To answer your question in Example 3: No, you don't. This will work perfectly fine as well:

```
echo "2 + 3 = " . $var1 + $var2 . "<br>";
```

Hopefully I've made a few things more clear for you. Please keep in mind though that this website is more for specific problems than extra explanation on your education. If you don't understand something, ask your teacher or find some forum more suitable for this. If you've got a specific problem, we're here for you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not getting the results that you predict.  echo "2 + 3 = $var1 + $var2<br>"; returns 2 + 3 = 2 + 3 and echo "2 + 3 = " . $var1 + $var2 . "<br>"; returns 5.

Comment: @John Maher You want to see something really messed up. Try echoing `echo "hello " . 2 + 3 . "world";` It won't be what you'd expect. And here's why, and this is really annoying on PHP's part. Concatenation has a higher priority than addition. Yep...

Comment: @Andrei thanks!!  You found the problem!!  Based on your comment I was able to find the solution.